# Can I have 0.03V in the input of an OpAmp? If can, what type of OpAmp can I use?

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, boost

I want use OpAmp as amplifier to increase my voltage. I have as input voltage 0,03VDC.

I want increase it to become 5VDC in output.

If I cannot use the OpAmp what type of circuit I should use to increase my voltage?

I tried to use voltage doubler, but it doesn't is not worked.

Comment: Is 0.03V the only supply voltage available?

Comment: Can you post your circuit of voltage doubler?

Comment: An op-amp circuit could amplify or offset an input signal from 0.03 V to 5 V. But only if it is provided with a power supply voltage somewhere above +5 V. What are you actually trying to do, and what power sources do you have available?

Comment: Is this question about a 30mV *signal* or about drawing *power* from a 30mV source?

Comment: to  Butzke the voltage i get is i have two circuit one is send voltage by coil and other circuit is  receiver have coil at  100 cm i get o,o3 v

Comment: to the photon, i can not use 5 voltage because i have sending voltage by wireless. What are you actually trying to do? is i want have 5 voltage at 100 cm the power sources i receiver coil.

Comment: Wireless power at 100cm is going to require a large coil - describe your sender and reciever coils.

Comment: 1- Thickness 1 mm.
2- Number of turns is three.
3- diameter is 5 inch. for both coil

Comment: You said in your question the dc voltage is 0.03V - do you actually measure 0.03V dc or is it an ac measurement? What frequency is the ac power applied to the transmit coil? I think circuits are needed to help you on this one dude. 100cm is a big distance to expect anything more than a few percent energy transfer with coils that are only 5" diameter but there are probably a few tricks you can learn BUT we need information from you.

Comment: i use bridge diode to convert it to dc see http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/90455/transfer-power-by-wireless

Comment: It's customary in English to use a period (.) as the decimal separator rather than a comma (,). [Reference](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/1453/2028)

Comment: @user32622, In that case you can **not** use an op-amp to do what you want. An op-amp needs power supplied to it from a DC supply, typically 2.5 V or more (even 20, 30, or 40 V for some op-amps), in order to amplify a signal.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to convert 30mVdc to 5V by using an energy harvest technique you may be disappointed. The lowest voltage energy harvester that I'm aware of is this: -

[image]

I'd be interested if anyone else can find a better one. This isn't a challenge by the way!

If on the other hand you are looking to amplify 0.03V to a 5V level then use an op-amp in non-inverting configuration with a gain of 166.7. This is easily achieved BUT you need a power source slightly greater than 5V to power the op-amp.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick you are indeed correct - I'll amend accordingly.

Comment: Cool. Amazing chip. Now I know what to ask Santa for this xmas!

Comment: Haven't really looked into this much, but I have heard of Joule Thieves being built from MOSFETs, and there are some handy dandy *zero-threshold MOSFETs* out there.

http://electronicdesign.com/analog/zero-threshold-fet-devices-run-unbiased-consume-microwatts

and

http://aldinc.com/pdf/ALD110800.pdf

Comment: Also, that is by far not the lowest input voltage booster out there.  This one works from 20mV input

http://www.linear.com/product/LTC3108

Comment: @krb686 I only said it was the lowest one I'm aware of and I also said I was interested in someone finding a better one. I think 20mV may be pushing it but it looks like it'll start up from about 100mV. Good device though.